# For bounded linear operators is it true that $(T_1+T_2)x=T_1x+T_2x$?

Tags: functional-analysis

I wounder if the above is true just from the definition for bounded linear operators, ie by requireing for some linear operator $T$ that $||Tx||\le c||x||$, or if this is a relationship that needs to be defined, ie that we define some set of bounded linear operators to be a vector space, $(T_1+T_2)x=T_1x+T_2x$? and $(\alpha T)x=\alpha Tx$. Maybe the above is true for linear operators in general?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's the definition of $T_1+T_2$, regardless of whether they're linear or bounded. For any functions with values in a space where you can add, $(f+g)(x) = f(x)+g(x)$ is the definition of the addition of functions.

Comment: Also, the "linear" bit means that $T(x_1 + x_2) = Tx_1 + Tx_2$ (and that $T(cx) = cTx$ for scalar $c$).

Comment: In what spaces can you add functions then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key thing to note here is that you need to start by defining the operations $+$ and scalar multiplication. If $T_{1}\colon X\rightarrow Y$ and $T_{2}\colon X\rightarrow Y$ and $Y$ is a vector space over some scalar field $F$, then the obvious definition is to take $T_{1}+T_{2}$ to be the operator that maps each $x\in X$ to $T_{1}x+T_{2}x$. That is,
$$
\left(T_1 + T_2\right)x \equiv T_1x + T_2x \quad \forall x\in X.
$$

Likewise, for scalar multiplication, take $\alpha T_{1}$ to be the operator that maps $x\in X$ to $\alpha T_{1}x$ whenever $\alpha \in F$. That is,
$$
\left(\alpha T_1\right) x \equiv \alpha \left( T_1 x \right) \quad \forall x \in X.
$$

These definitions are independent of the linearity / boundedness of the operators.